# CSS Background positions

Tags: html, css, blogger

In trying to finalize the layout for my blog, I am having one issue I cant seem to get past. I have two different backgrounds that I want to use for my blog. One of the backgrounds is used just for the header of the blog. The other background I want to add is for the rest. I have been trying to find a way to get my body background to repeat after so much spacing with little luck.

If there is a way to have a background repeat-y after a certain position that would be perfect. But that doesn't seem possible from my searches. If there is another way to accomplish this, it would be very helpful.

[This is the site](http://www.raisedwithgaming.com) I am trying to edit.

As you can see, the header has the proper background, but I cant figure a way to get that background everywhere else. For clarification, the background header has a blue background under the home/search buttons, so that is why I cant just have one repeating header.

I just made a few edits to my site, and I got to to look very close to how I want. I did more of a quick fix that is "good enough". I just made the header background repeat, and it looks pretty good for the most part. The only problem with it now is that the blue bar that is part of the header sometimes shows up at the bottom of the screen, which is okay I guess. If anyone has a better solution I would love to hear it.

Comment: Why not just replace `no-repeat` with `repeat-y` on the `wrapper`?

Comment: I am trying to avoid that because the background you are seeing has that blue bar behind the home button. I am trying to edit a premade template and they decided not to make that bar have it's own background and just inherit the main background.

Comment: Then I would suggest stripping it into two parts, that way it will be even easier to maintain and update.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do currently. But I cant figure out a way to create a background that repeats after a given amount of space. For example I want my lower background to start repeating after the header background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify "repeat-y" then there is no posibility as far as I know to make the background begin repeating after some coordinate.

However, since you have 2 different backgrounds, you don't need to.

Just specify the non repeating background first, and with the adequate dimensions; it will hide the other

This CSS

```
.test1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black, red), linear-gradient(0deg, white, yellow);
    background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px;
    background-size: 100% 100px, 100% 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;    
}
```

produces a black & red top, followed by a repeating pattern of yellow stripes

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/qedag/)

It is not clear from your example if this is enough; if not you would need another background, between the first and the second, to hide the amount of the repeating background needed

Comment: This might be exactly what I need. I will test this in the morning when I get the time and get back to you. Thanks a ton.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had to do a little format editing to make it look how I wanted, but this structure is perfect. [Here is the update](http://www.raisedwithgaming.com/)